# Looping through a dictionary of dataframes and counting a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am wondering if anyone can help. I have a number of dataframes stored in a dictionary. I simply want to access each of these dataframes and count the values in a column in the column I have 10 letters. In the first dataframe there are 5bs and 5 as. For example the output from the count I would expect to be is a = 5 and b =5. However for each dataframe this count would be different hence I would like to store the output of these counts either into another dictionary or a separate variable.

The dictionary is called Dict and the column name in all the dataframes is called letters. I have tried to do this by accessing the keys in the dictionary but can not get it to work. A section of what I have tried is shown below.

`import pandas as pd
 for key in Dict:
     Count=pd.value_counts(key['letters'])`

Count here would ideally change with each new count output to store into a new variable

A simplified example (the actual dataframe sizes are max 5000,63) of the one of the 14 dataframes in the dictionary would be

`d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'letters': ['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

The other dataframes are names df2,df3,df4 etc

I hope that makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of a dataframe from the dictionary?

Comment: Thanks I have edited the original question and given an example

Comment: That doesn't give an example of the larger dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access both key and values when iterating over a dictionary, you should use the items function.
You could use another dictionary to store the results:

```
letter_counts = {}
for key, value in Dict.items():
    letter_counts[key] = value["letters"].value_counts()
```

You could also use dictionary comprehension to do this in 1 line:

```
letter_counts = {key: value["letters"].value_counts() for key, value in Dict.items()}
```

Comment: this does not "store the output of these counts either into another dictionary or a separate variable." Count is overwritten with every iteration and not appended anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Daniel is there a way to change the variable Count each time for every dataframe. So I have the results of count of each dataframe stored in separate variables.

Comment: Try and declare counts before the for loop, and then in each iteration add to it

Comment: I edited the answer to store the results in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is probably dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'letters': ['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b']}
d2 = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'letters': ['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b','a']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df_dict = {'d': df, 'd2': df2}

new_dict = {k: v['letters'].count() for k,v in df_dict.items()}

# out
{'d': 10, 'd2': 11}
```